# What is the meaning of "not_contained" constraint of Interaction in UML 2.5.1

Tags: uml, language-lawyer, interaction

UML Specification 2.5.1, section, 17.12.11.5 provides information about contstraints of the Interaction Classifier. The constraint not_contained is explained as the following:

> An Interaction instance must not be contained within another Interaction instance.

```
inv: enclosingInteraction->isEmpty()
```

Now, when I look at Figure 17.1 which shows the abstract syntax of interactions, I see that the Interaction classifier is a generalization of Fragment classifier. Therefore, an Interaction is a Fragment, but not vice versa.

[image]

Additionally, Interaction classifier has the "fragment" association, the "enclosingInteraction" classifier is an association of the Fragment classifier. Then, how can we define the above constraint as a constraint of the Interaction classifier? Interaction classifier should have no attribute "enclosingInteraction".

Is my interpretation of the abstract syntax wrong? In my understanding, above OCL definition would only be applicable to the Fragment classifier, not the Interaction Classifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> inv: enclosingInteraction->isEmpty()

Referring to the abstract syntax that means when an *InteractionFragment* is an *Interaction* then *enclosingInteraction* is empty (its size is 0).

Without that constraint an *Interaction* can have an enclosing *Interaction* and then the following can be false :

> An Interaction instance must not be contained within another Interaction instance.

---

The goal of the relation is to allow an *Interaction* to know its *InteractionFragment*, and an *InteractionFragment* to know its containing *Interaction*, and thanks to the bidirectional association it is not possible to have :

[image]

having no sense but allowed in case of :

[image]

A way to not have the necessary constraint is to introduce an additional class :

[image]

but this is not the choice made in UML meta model

---

In fact in all the other cases of specialization of *InteractionFragment* the *enclosingInteraction* is not empty (its size is 1) because all of them cannot exist out of an *Interaction* :

- *OccurrenceSpecification* : from § 17.12.23.5 of [formal/2017-12-05](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/)

> covered : Lifeline [1..1]{redefines InteractionFragment::covered} (opposite A_covered_events::events) References the Lifeline on which the OccurrenceSpecification appears.

- *StateInvariant* : from 17.12.25.4 of [formal/2017-12-05](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/)

> covered : Lifeline [1..1]{redefines InteractionFragment::covered} (opposite
> A_covered_stateInvariant::stateInvariant)
> References the Lifeline on which the StateInvariant appears.

- *ExecutionSpecification* : from 17.12.8.1 of [formal/2017-12-05](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/)

> An ExecutionSpecification is a specification of the execution of a unit of Behavior or Action within the Lifeline

---

> Interaction classifier should have no attribute "enclosingInteraction"

Note *enclosingInteraction* is defined on *InteractionFragment*, *Interaction* inherits it.

Comment: @qwerty_so it is not not directly said in the standard but they cannot exist out of an interaction so they have an enclosing interaction

Comment: @qwerty_so are you saying even they are in an interaction their enclosingInteraction  is empty ? that has no sense for me

Comment: @qwerty_so If there are no LifeLine there are no OccurrenceSpecification nor StateInvariant nor ExecutionSpecification too, so what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

Avoid loops in your behavior description.

### Long version

`Interaction`

> An Interaction is a unit of Behavior that focuses on the observable exchange of information between connectable elements.

So that describes a certain piece of your code. An `Interaction` itself is an `InteractionFragment`

> InteractionFragment is an abstract notion of the most general interaction unit. An InteractionFragment is a piece of an Interaction. Each InteractionFragment is conceptually like an Interaction by itself.

This in turn (being abstract) is concretized by `OccurrenceSpecification`

> An OccurrenceSpecification is the basic semantic unit of Interactions. The sequences of occurrences specified by them are the meanings of Interactions.

`ExecutionSpecification` (also being abstract)

> An ExecutionSpecification is a specification of the execution of a unit of Behavior or Action within the Lifeline. The duration of an ExecutionSpecification is represented by two OccurrenceSpecifications, the start OccurrenceSpecification and the finish OccurrenceSpecification.

or `StateInvariant`

> A StateInvariant is a runtime constraint on the participants of the Interaction. It may be used to specify a variety of different kinds of Constraints, such as values of Attributes or Variables, internal or external States, and so on. A StateInvariant is an InteractionFragment and it is placed on a Lifeline.

Each of them describe behavior from a different aspect.

An `Interaction` has a `+enclodingIteraction`inherited from the `InteractionFragment` which references any `Interaction` instance.

Now the constraint just says that once you have such an instance it may occur only once and not in some recursive description. So you can split behavior in any tiny pieces but you must not repeat one of them.

---

Quotations taken from the descriptions in the meta model of UML 2.5.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, indeed both answers solved my question, I just accepted bruno's answer due to the fact that it was the first answer.